# SSSD - Session terminates immediately

Tags: linux, shell, active-directory

My Active Directory user authentication via SSSD worked flawlessly, but after adding the "group" option via YAST (also lookup AD groups on login) it showed me an endless loop of SSSD errors, so I unchecked the option again, restarted the SSSD daemon and upon trying to login with an AD user, I get immediately logged out.

This is my sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = ssh,pam,nss
domains = mydomain.local

[pam]

[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash

[ssh]

[domain/mydomain.local]
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
enumerate = false
cache_credentials = false
case_sensitive = true
ad_server = AD-01,AD-02
```

System: SLES 12 SP2

After a bit of try and error, I found out that putting the line `/bin/bash` into the startup profile script (.profile), the session stays open.
So the error must be with SMB or SSSD not opening a shell on login automatically.

With `ssh user@server echo $SHELL` I get /bin/bash, even when setting default_shell and/or the override_shell in the sssd.conf to /bin/sh.

What am I missing here?

Edit: After reading @Ed Grimm's suggestion, I tried the SSH command with quotes, it returns /bin/sh (if I change it in the sshd.conf), so it pulls it correctly. Still doesn't get me any closer as to why it doesn't open a shell upon login though...

Comment: Most of that is out of my expertise, but the `$SHELL` is getting expanded by your local command line before contacting the other server because you don't have a backslash in front of the $ and you haven't single-quoted it either.  (Don't do both of those, or it will just echo back `$SHELL`.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the quotes, wasn't thinking of that. Returns /bin/sh now.